# Validar boton de SweetAlert en JS

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

Quisiera saber como validar si es presionado el boton de `agregar` de `sweetAlert`, en mi condicion estoy manejando cantidades si la que se quiere ingresar es mayor a su `cantidad maxima` permitida, le haga saber que esta sobrepasando y si elige `agregar` haga el siguiente proceso.

```
    if (parseInt(cantidad) > parseInt(max))
    {
        swal({
        title: "La cantidad es mayor a su cantidad maxima",
        text: "¿Seguro que desea agregarlos?",
        icon: "warning",
        buttons: ["Cancelar", "Agregar"],   });

    //condicion de validacion boton Agregar SweetAlert
{
 //siguiente proceso
}       
        }
```

Comment: Estas utilizando `Sweet Alert 2` ?

Comment: Efectivamente @A.Palacio.

Comment: En la documentación puedes encontrar un ejemplo de cuando se presiona el boton de confirmar [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) es el ejemplo numero 8.

Answer (score 0):

Según la documentación de SweetAlert2, te serviría realizar la(s) validacion(es) que necesites, mediante el callback then de la siguiente forma

```js
function showAlert(){
  swal({
    title: 'Ingrese un valor máximo de 10',
    input: 'text'
  }).then((result) => {
    if(result.value > 10)
      swal('Valor superado D:');
    else
      swal('Todo bien :D');
  })
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.29.0/sweetalert2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container mt-2">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="showAlert()">Mostrar popup</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/7.29.0/sweetalert2.all.js"></script>
```

Nos comentas :)

Comment: Edite la publicacion amigo, era Sweet Alert..Me confundi, disculpa.

Comment: @VirusDetected Editada :)

Answer (score 0):

Esta respuesta es con SweetAlert [1](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#advanced-examples)

Declaras los botones y validas la repuesta de alguno por el nombre del botón

[Enlace](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#advanced-examples)

```js
swal("La cantidad es mayor a su cantidad maxima", "¿Seguro que desea agregarlos?", "info", {
  buttons: {
    cancelar: { text: "Cancelar"
    },
    agregar: {
      text: "Agregar"
    },
  },
})
.then((value) => {
  switch (value) {
 
    case "cancelar":
      swal("No agregado","","warning");
       //CODIGO DE NO AGREGADO O LO QUE QUIERAS HACER
      break;
 
    case "agregar":
      swal("Agreado", "La cantidad era mayor pero fue agregada por su solicitud", "success");
      //AQUI CODIGO DONDE AGREGAS
      break;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```